# Highcharts : Custom legends in boxplot chart

Tags: .net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

In highcharts when you a draw a boxplot chart and enable legend, it only shows name of one series in legend as highlighted below.

[image]

But actually this series comprises of 5 sub-series one each for minimum, maximum, median, lower quartile, upper quartile. values.It's like combining data of 5 series into one and plotting boxplot chart. 
Is there a way to show 5 legend items corresponding to each sub-series(e.g mimimum, median etc..) in highcharts

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saurabhinvit/g9hs4xaa/)

```
series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [
                [760, 801, 848, 895, 965],
                [733, 853, 939, 980, 1080],
                [714, 762, 817, 870, 918],
                [724, 802, 806, 871, 950],
                [834, 836, 864, 882, 910]
            ]
        }]
```

Comment: Since an OHLC/candlestick/boxplot chart is actually one series it would be best to show this in the tooltip. This is actually one single series. If you want to have it broken up then break up the data series yourself. What would your legend actually look like?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you want a legend entry for each box, or that you want a legend entry for each piece of the box? It seems like you're asking for the latter, which I can't find a way to make sense. What would be the desired result and use case?

Comment: Hm... something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g9hs4xaa/3/ ? Just split main series into separate ones.

Comment: Found a hacky way to solve this </br>http://jsfiddle.net/saurabhinvit/fbqfes07/3/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @Paweł Fus, http://jsfiddle.net/g9hs4xaa/3/

```
series: [{data: [[0, 760, 801, 848, 895, 965]]}, 
     {data: [[1, 733, 853, 939, 980, 1080]]}, 
     {data: [[2, 714, 762, 817, 870, 918]]}, 
     {data: [[3, 724, 802, 806, 871, 950]]}, 
     {data: [[4, 834, 836, 864, 882, 910]]}]
```

Separating series data is the closest we can get. But there's still an issue when deselecting a particular legend, the corresponding box disappears but not the xAxis category.

So taking the above fiddle's example if we deselect Series 2, the box appears but xAxis category - "2" still appears with an empty space in between 1 and 3. Similarly if we remove 2,3,4 then we end up with only 2 boxes at the corners which doesn't look good.

Couldn't find a reliable solution to this online! Is this a highchart bug or am I missing something here?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZXUu.png)